# The $GLOBALS do not get the expected data

Tags: php

I have the bellow php code:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="num1">
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="num2">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="func1">Submit</button>
</form>

The result is: <?php
if (isset($GLOBALS['result'])) {
    echo $GLOBALS['result'];  // there do not get the add result.
}
?>


<?php

$GLOBALS['result'] = 0;


if(isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['submit'] == 'func1'){
    $num1 = $_GET['num1'];
    $num2 = $_GET['num2'];

    $GLOBALS['result'] = $num1 + $num2;

}

?>
```

The issue is `if (isset($GLOBALS['result'])) {...}` the code did not walk through.

Where is my issue? 
Or how can I use a variables in different php tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code
It is working.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="num1">
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="num2">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="func1">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['submit'] == 'func1'){
    $num1 = $_GET['num1'];
    $num2 = $_GET['num2'];

    $_SESSION['result'] = ($num1 + $num2); 

}

?>

The result is: <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['result'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['result'];  // there do not get the add result.  
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you, bro, but there still a issue for me, if the `The result is: <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['result'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['result'];  // there do not get the add result.  
}
?>` is before the `if(isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['submit'] == 'func1')` php code, there will not update as my requirement.

Comment: If you place that block above the submit condition then you will not get desired result as it will then need a page refresh to update your session variable.

Comment: or use header location for same page in that if condition below  $_SESSION['result'] = ($num1 + $num2);  to get that value

Answer (score 0):

The page gets refreshed after submitting the form.
So the value get reset in GLOBALS.

If you can echo GLOBALS inside the submit condition then you will get the values.

Note : Use SESSION instead of GLOBALS.

```
<?php
     if(isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['submit'] == 'func1'){
            $num1 = $_GET['num1'];
            $num2 = $_GET['num2'];

            $GLOBALS['result'] = $num1 + $num2;

             echo $GLOBALS['result'];

        }
?>
```

Comment: I know I can put the php echo code in there, but I want to realize the different 
php tag place for using the  variable, I tried use `$_SESSION['result']` to store it, but still can not get it.